# Factory reset for Canon MF4690 ImageClass?

Tags: printer, reset

I have a Canon MF4690 ImageClass. It has a lot of issues working with SMB. I've already tried to use the web interface for it which crashes after a few page views. I have called Canon support several times and they refuse to give me the factory reset so I can restore it to factory settings, because I don't have the paid receipt for this printer. I've never had a product that I couldn't restore to factory settings, and need to give this a try before recycling and banning Canon products entirely. Sorry for the frustration, but this is not some huge enterprise product, it's a multifunction thing that was sold at Staples.

I have some similar instructions for factory reset of Canon printers, but none of them have the exact same interface I have seen so far. So I would need specific to the MF4690 model. If you have something close to it that might work, I am willing to give it a try. Trying to be "green" to continue to get use out of this product.

I have located the Service Manual for the MF4690 online, but I don't see mention of how to do a factory reset. It talks about Service Mode but I can't figure it out:
http://cms.cmexonline.com.mx/media/canon/manuales/fichero/116_imageCLASS_MF4690_ServiceManual_EN_A4.pdf

The above Service Manual does describe how to enter service mode. This DOES WORK to get into service mode:

```
1) Enter service mode.
Press the operation panel Additional functions key, 2 key, 8 key and Additional functions key in this order.
```

So withe MF4690 powered on, I pressed the following keys:

```
Additional Functions
2
8
Additional Functions
```

The following prompt appeared on the LCD display:

```
#SSSW
```

The Service Manual says SSSW is Service Soft Switch Settings (SSSW). While I have not figure out how to do the factory reset/restore yet, I have been able to enter this mode so far. I'm concerned that I proceed carefully because I don't want to "brick" the printer if that's even a possibly.

Comment: If you contact Canon, they will provide this detail but you may need to send them proof of purchase (based upon what I've read)

Comment: Yes, Dave, you are correct. But I no longer have access to the receipt for this product. Canon said they couldn't release the information without the receipt. I don't know what more I could do to prove I bought and own this printer and it's being used in my office.

Answer (score 1):

Well i think this is too late but i finally could reset...

Here the proceess..

```
Additional Functions
2
8
Additional Functions
move to option  - #clear -  with nav panel (< ok >) keys,
press ok 
select option - All -
Please wait is displayed in screen, 
after some minutes (4 aprox) Its done!! all the settings were reset.
```

Just configure again. I also tried with the other options under #clear menu but nothing worked.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

From the website fixya.com, i found the following:

hold menu and #
press down to select clear
press Start/Copy

http://www.fixya.com/support/t14316754-reset_canon_mf4690_factory_default

Give it a try and let us know if it worked!

Comment: Thanks, but there is no Menu key on the MF4690.

Comment: Hi, what a bummer. Have you tried to log on to the printer interface and look around for a factory reset there? As last resort I would try to give their technicians a call: +27 12 675 4900

Comment: Yes, nothing on the printer's web interface. The web interface also crashes are a few page views too. I've call their tech support they won't give out the factory reset/store info unless you send them a copy of your paid sales receipt for the printer.

Comment: Seems like you are stuck here - http://www.amazon.com/Canon-imageCLASS-MF4690-Monochrome-1827B001/product-reviews/B000NUW42E?pageNumber=3 - this guy also claims he couldnt find anything regarding a hard reset anywhere and technical support also refused to give him any information unless they receive PoP. Sorry I couldnt help, but who wouldve thought it could be this difficult?

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation (it would appear) and no way of getting it from Canon since you don't have the receipt.

I wouldn't rule out buying a new one if this is causing hassle which I think is your only realistic option (or seeing if you know anyone who has one (with receipt) and asking them to do it for you), or buying another for your office, calling support and then you can either use the new printer or maybe exchange it for store credit or similar (or, keep it boxed and return it new).

Answer (score -1):

Using **Canon printer factory reset** to solve problems after a **Canon printer firmware upgrade.**

I have used the solution provided by ppundo to solve a LAN network connection problem, losing network communication to my i-Sensys MF8340Cdn printer after a Canon firmware upgrade, - not being able to find any help on Canon on-line support!

Similar solutions to Canon imageCLASS or i-Sensys MF family printers from various different problems, are provided by [Udo Rader at BestSolution](http://riaschissl.bestsolution.at/2013/11/factory-reset-a-canon-mf8330cdn/) and on the [SpiceWorks](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/198760-canon-mf8380-factory-reset?page=1#entry-5528161) site.

I haven't been able to post my solution here, as the Super User 'spam blocks' my problem description, analysis and solution, so please visit BestSolution or SpiceWorks, to read the full story on how-to do a firmware update and subsequent factory reset to get your printer back, performing an initial setup once again.

Comment: You can quote the relevant parts of the linked content. I'm rather surprised that the content got blocked by the system.